# Are my wireless Microsoft mouse+keyboard supported in OSX?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mac-mini, mouse

I have a MS Wireless Laser Mouse/Keyboard 5000 set where both connect to my Windows desktop using a special USB bluetooth receiver.

I'm not sure if this is generic USB technology that will work on my Mac Mini (2012), running OSX Yosemite - I am hoping to switch to that as my main device.

Can anyone tell me if it will/should work without problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from MS driver download sites http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/wireless-mouse-5000 & http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/p/wireless-comfort-desktop-5000#support they will be natively supported in anything newer than 10.7.

If not, try those drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, even [Microsoft itself](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/fr-fr/p/wireless-comfort-desktop-5000) says it's compatible with OSX !